# How to set up main class in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, program-entry-point

Here is structure of my project:

[image]

The main method is in Receipt.java. I am trying to set up main class.In my opinion it should be like this:

[image]

However it doesn't work. I also tried **receipt.idea.Receipt**. 
I am new to java and be thankfull for help.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/

Comment: The main method in the class should have a Play sign on the left. Click it and it will setup everything for you.

Answer (score 1):

You probably downloaded this program from somewhere. Your problem is that files are out of source. Simply right click on the java sources folder ("receipt) and select Mark Directory As > Sources Root. Then you ll see the "c" symbol in your classes and a play where the main is!

Answer (score -1):

I know 3 ways to set it:

1. Manually with the `Edit configurations`

   [image]
2. Clicking on the Play icon next to the main method:

   [image]
3. Right clicking on your class and choosing `Run 'MyClass.main()'`

   [image]